# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzUU()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp;

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, android-studio

i'm making a food delivery app here is the error which i'm facing, please help me to get out of it.

> Blockquote
>   (ZygoteInit.java:1120)

```
05-05 10:31:37.666 25756-25791/com.example.lenovo.laundry D/FA: Logging event (FE): app_exception(_ae), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=crash, timestamp=1525496497673, fatal=1}]
05-05 10:31:37.906 25756-25756/com.example.lenovo.laundry E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Process: com.example.lenovo.laundry, PID: 25756

    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzUU()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.lenovo.laundry-1/base.apk)
                                                                                at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                                at com.example.lenovo.laundry.home.onCreate(home.java:46)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

code of gradle(app)

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:15.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

please help me....

Comment: show you top level build gradle

Comment: You must use `firebase-ui-database:3.3.1` for [compatibility with Firebase SDK 15.0.0](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'
```

to

```
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
```

Please see [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) the compatibility between the versions of FirebaseUI and Firebase/Play Services.